pyrcc5 error occurred while parsing reference
I am trying to follow the tutorial here: https://realpython.com/python-menus-toolbars/#using-icons-and-resources-in-pyqt
So, I wrote me a .qrc file:
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
  <file alias="MY&C-LOGO-2020.svg">resources/MY&C-LOGO-2020.svg</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>

... and then I do:
$ pyrcc5 -o qrc_resources.py resources.qrc
pyrcc5 Parse Error:resources.qrc:3:34 [error occurred while parsing reference]

Well, great, thanks for that very useful error message. (If 3:34 means line 3, column 34, that is the closing double quote).
So, how do I proceed from here? What on earth could have gone wrong, and how do I debug this?

The most obvious culprit is the &: while not technically forbidden, is still a special character, and the parser doesn't seem able to deal with it. Rename the icon without that character.

Well, apparently ampersand (&) is not allowed character here; seemingly the alias might end up being used as key of a dict, so absolutely no & there; and for some reason, the file path started working when I "escaped" the ampersand (&) with the HTML entities variant &amp;; so the corrected file is:
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
  <file alias="MYC-LOGO-2020.svg">resources/MY&amp;C-LOGO-2020.svg</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>

Ughh.. why does no one on the internet mention this; or at least write a more descriptive error (e.g. "error occurred while parsing reference: cannot parse character &" or something)

The error comes from QXmlStreamReader, which by default just returns the document position and a generic error. Standard QRC files are normally created by Designer, which obviously follows the XML syntax (requiring proper escaping with the &amp; entity) and their schema, so Qt developers probably didn't think it was necessary to add further output: nobody prevents you to write the XML file by hand, but you need to know how to do it properly. You were probably looking for solutions related to Qt/rcc, but you wouldn't find any because the problem was that you wrote a malformed XML file.
